# How can I ignore the PayPal description box in codeigniter?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

[I don't want the box with the image mentioned, I want the direct paypal login option. How do I solve?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qccW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Include an `item_name` for description in your transaction details when setting up the transaction, so that the 'box' is not necessary.

For full details, see the HTML variables documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/